# About Javascript window.open(input path here);

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav.lessons>li').click(function  () {
    $id=$(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
    window.open( $id+"/" + this.id + ".php");
})
</script>
```

this code will open a php file from my chapter1/lesson1.php and so on

i got code from the internet
im just wondering how to change the

```
window.open( $id+"/" + this.id + ".php");
```

because i want to open it on the path student/chapter1/lesson1.php

Comment: What is your question about that code?

Comment: window.open( $id+"/" + this.id + ".php");
i just want to add an student/ is this code but i cant

Comment: `"student/" + $id + "/" + this.id + ".php"`—if you start with code you just got from the internet, your first step should be to try to understand how it works before you look for how to make it do something else.

Comment: sorry for the trouble and thank you for helping me, i just jumped of html php to javascript so im kinda newbie in javascripting

Answer (score 0):

This is just a string concatination issue - you can add the "student" at the beginning of the string:

```
window.open("student/" + $id + "/" + this.id + ".php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `window.open("student/" + $id + "/" + this.id + ".php");`